# Choose controller to run AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-controller

I'm trying to run certain controller depending from API response.

Starting with routeProvider config:

```
.when('/objects/:objectId', {
    controller: ControllerChooseCtrl,
    template: '<div></div>'
})
```

For example we have such format of API response - {"available": true/false}

```
function ControllerChooseCtrl($scope, $routeParams){

    $http('...', {object_id: $routeParams.objectId}).then(function(data){

        $scope.resolved_data = data;

        if (data.available){
            // run AvaibleController
            // with 'available-template.html'
        } else {
            // run NotAvailableController
            // with 'not-available-template.html'
        }

    })  
}
```

.

```
function AvaibleController($scope){
    // use resolved_data from parent controller
}


function NotAvaibleController($scope){
    // use resolved_data from parent controller
}
```

So, there at least two questions:

1. How to run specific controller depending on API response.
2. How to pass API response to executable controller, to avoid request repeating.

Comment: it sounds like you try to use the child-controllers as if they were directives. In your template, what about just inlduing different child directives depending on condition with a ng-if ?

Comment: should also make this request in `resolve` of router